# Blender 3.1.2 M1 chip- Metal- GPU enabled- cycles on but NO CAUSTIC checkbox

Tags: lighting, gpu, glass, versions, caustics

According to tutorials with the uplisted settings I should have the opinion to see "caustics" checkboxes under object properties, but there are no caustic boxes.
I use MacBook Air m1 chip with metal, latest blender version. Thanks you if you can help me.

Comment: I believe that it only works in CPU mode at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Caustics was in the 3.1 Alpha for Metal but did not make it into the final 3.1 release:
https://developer.blender.org/D13533#381586

Comment: thank you Tobias, can I still download 3.1 alpha from blender.org?

Comment: I was not able to find it, unfortunately. You might want to try the current 3.2 alpha instead. Though, I’m not sure if the caustics for metal is in there.